# Rails: Soft Delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, named-scope

I am fairly new to Rails. I am building a digital library.

I would love to add the option of **soft delete** to my application.

For now I have added a column **delete** with boolean datatype to my table and I have also defined the action in my controller for the soft delete, but I am facing issues with defining the scope for the soft delete action in the model, so that the action can be called in the controller.

I want a scope for the soft delete that is false by default, and then when i delete a book, it updates to true in the database.

**Controller Action**

```
def softdelete
    @book.softdelete
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to books_url, notice: 'Book was successfully deleted.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

**Soft Delete Migration**

```
class AddDeleteToBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :books, :delete, :boolean, :null =>  true
  end
end
```

What I have left is how to define the method for soft delete in the book model.

Comment: I'd look into using a gem for this purpose, take a look at paranoia or discard gem. Makes your life a lot easier.

Comment: but I'll write a short answer for this as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you would like to do is create a softdelete method, that updates the delete field (I think you need to rename it, since it is a reserved word in Rails)

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  #add a model scope to fetch only non-deleted records
  scope :not_deleted, -> { where(soft_deleted: false) }
  scope :deleted, -> { where(soft_deleted: true) }

  #create the soft delete method
  def soft_delete
    update(soft_deleted: true)
  end

  # make an undelete method
  def undelete
    update(soft_deleted: false)
  end
end
```

And update your controller to fetch only undeleted records from now on

```
 def index
   @books = Book.not_deleted
 end
```

Comment: How do I define the route for books/soft_delete? I want the soft_delete action to update its table from false to true.

I have defined the route as
`put '/soft_delete' => 'books#soft_delete'`

But calling it on the views 
`<%= link_to 'Soft Delete', book, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }`

seems not to work

Comment: You dont... you just use the default destroy route... you only call the soft_delete method on the model object instead of destroy.

Comment: So to further clarify, you need to keep your routes en controller actions like the standard ones, but instead of calling destroy, you call soft_delete.

Comment: The problem with that is that I don't actually want to delete it, I still want to update the soft_delete table in the database from true to false.

Comment: Here's a link to the new issue that I am having with the soft_delete function after implementing the soft_delete function. https://stackoverflow.com/q/56242805/10907864

Comment: The name of route and controller action don’t have any impact on the method that you are calling on the object. In this case you would call normal destroy path, as is standard in rails, but call the soft_delete method instead of the actual delete.

Comment: After a long time of trying different approaches, I have now understood what you meant. I guess you should have explained to me better with probably an example since I am still junior in Ruby on Rails. I believe that what you wanted me to do was to replace `@book.destroy' with `@book.soft_delete` in the destroy action of the books controller. Thank you so much for your assistance, I truly appreciate.

Comment: YW, if you read back my comments, you will see that I pointed this out multiple times. If you are not familiar with some of the Rails terminology I used, you should google to seek their definitions. I think anyone with decent OOP / Rails knowledge would have understood my comments. Plus since your profile says you are gifted, I thought you would understand ;)

Comment: Hahahahahaha, that gifted part